# How can I handle false as null for any primitive or boxed numerical bean property in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

I've been struggling with an issue. My endpoint receives a lot of broken API calls from a PHP application where there are often `false` booleans set for numerical fields.

How can I attach a custom deserializer to my `ObjectMapper` that would convert all `false` values to `null` or `0` depending upon the type of the corresponding numerical property in the bean?

Here's the JSON:

```
{  
    "name": "My Name",
    "image_url": null,
    "price": false
    "list_price": false;
}
```

Here's an example of the bean:

```
public class Item {

    public String name;
    public String imageUrl;
    public Double price;
    public double listPrice;
}
```

I've only a custom deserializer along the lines of this but this means that I explicitly need to attach this to every field:

```
public class FalseAsNullDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private final Class targetType;

    private FalseAsNullDeserializer() {
        this.targetType = null;
        // required by Jackson
    }

    public FalseAsNullDeserializer(Class<?> targetType) {
        this.targetType = targetType;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = parser.readValueAsTree();
        if (!node.isObject() && !node.asBoolean()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return JSONUtils.getMapper().treeToValue(node, targetType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext context, BeanProperty property)
            throws JsonMappingException {
        return new FalseAsNullDeserializer(property.getType().getRawClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: For the record: you shouldn't forget about punishing your PHP folks for their crappy output. Seriously: I would rather spent time "fixing" the source of your problems, instead of investing a lot of time symptom-fighting.